# Error in method syntax

Tags: c#

I tried to learn a little bit of C#, just for fun, and in one of my first applications when I tried to write method I got an error that I don't really understand:

> cs0116 a namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods

What did I do wrong? My Code:

```
public static void Reader (Wyborcy wyborca) 
   => Console.WriteLine("Dane: {0} {1} Klasa: {2}", wyborca.Name, wyborca.Surname, wyborca.Klasa);
```

Comment: what is the error

Comment: What do you mean by putting =>?

Comment: @alienflow that's C# 6 expression syntax.

Comment: @alienflow: That's an expression-bodied method, available from C# 6 onwards.

Comment: Wow then I got stuck in the past with C# haha

Comment: May I ask for the language version you build your application with? To find it :  Right click the project, Property, In the Build Tab click Advanced Option, then language.

Comment: Or [Edit] the information found with `Console.Write(typeof(string).Assembly.ImageRuntimeVersion);` into your question.

Comment: Your error indicates that you try to define this method directly in a namespace: `YourNamespace { YourMethod }`. Namespaces cannot directly contain methods or variables. Wrap your method inside a class like this: `YourNamespace { class MyClass { YourMethod } }`. This should do the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you put your method directly into a namespace without enclosing it with a class. You can get rid of that error by modifying your example the following way:

```
public class YourTestClass {
    public static void Reader (Wyborcy wyborca) => Console.WriteLine("Dane: {0} {1} Klasa: {2}", wyborca.Name, wyborca.Surname, wyborca.Klasa);
}
```

Then you can call your `Reader` method like this:

```
YourTestClass.Reader(wyborca);
```